# Teradata - Group the amount by product with the latest date of purchase in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I am new to Teradata, can anyone help me with below query.

I've a custom table with millions of records like given below :

[image: Custid Custname bill_no date product amount 5 A 201 11/12/2017 Tee 1100 5 A 301 11/12/2017 Shirt 1200 5 A 401 11/12/2017 Tee 1050 809 B 501 10/14/2017 Tee 230 809 B 601 10/14/2017 Shirt 580 809 B 701 10/14/2017 Short 950 809 B 801 10/14/2017 Shirt 340 809 B 901 10/14/2017 Tee 290 601 c 1001 11/18/2017 Shirt 1040 601 c 1101 11/18/2017 Tee 690 601 c 1201 11/18/2017 Short 250 601 c 1301 11/18/2017 Short 890 5 A 201 10/18/2017 Tee 2850 5 A 301 10/18/2017 Shirt 1700]

Basically, I need to group the amount by product with the latest date of purchase. The Columns I need is Cust_id, Cust_name, date, Product and amount.

Need the result set as below:

[image]

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did records with id `601` not included in desired output

Answer (score 3):

You can use aggregation along with `qualify` and `rank` to get your desired result.

```
select  Custid, custname, Date1, product, sum(amount) as amount
from table1
group by custid, custname, product, date1 
qualify rank() over(partition by custid, custname order by date1 desc) = 1
order by custname asc, date1 desc;
```

**Result:**

[image]

*P.S. It's not clear why records with id `601` are missing from your sample desired output*